# Plot the directed graph in Julia with vertices in fixed positions by x y coordinates

Tags: graph, julia, coordinates, directed-graph

I would like to plot a graph in Julia with a basic structure like the following picture, ignoring other irrelevant elements.

[A directed graph with vertices in fixed positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GyWh.jpg)

The matrix indicating directed edges is like the following:

```
mat_arcTwoNodes = [0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0;
                   0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0;
                   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1;
                   1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0;
                   0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0;
                   1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0;
                   0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0;
                   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0;
                   0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0;
                   0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0]
```

Besides, I have the x y coordinates for the ten vertices:

```
vec_xNode = [1    3    8    2    4    5    6    7    9    9]
vec_yNode = [1    2    1    7    9    5    3    7    9    4]
```

I know how to plot a directed graph from the matrix.

```
julia> using LightGraphs    
julia> using GraphPlot    
julia> G = DiGraph(mat_arcTwoNodes)
{10, 16} directed simple Int64 graph
julia> gplot(G)
```

But how can I plot the vertices in a fixed position like that in the picture using the x y coordinate?

This kind of visualization is important in the design of networks. Although we can analyze a graph without a specific visualization, I don't want to draw a graph with another way to visualize the final result. It's more comprehensive with fixed positions showing their relative distance.

Comment: This isn't currently possible in GraphPlot.jl, but see https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/GraphPlot.jl/issues/83 for a feature enhancement request.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I will just plot a normal figure with points being the vertices and lines representing the edges. Hope this can be done more elegantly in the future.

Comment: I take back my previous comment. Apparently there's a way to pass in `locs_x, locs_y` to `gplot`. This is currently undocumented but that'll be fixed soon. Give it a try (look at the `gplot` docstring).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
# Load the adjacency matrix and graph attributes
mat_arcTwoNodes = [0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0;
0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0;
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1;
1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0;
0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0;
1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0;
0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0;
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0;
0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0;
0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0]
vec_xNode = [1    3    8    2    4    5    6    7    9    9]
vec_yNode = [1    2    1    7    9    5    3    7    9    4]

# Load the packages
using LightGraphs, GraphPlot, MetaGraphs, GraphRecipes, Plots
# Create a generic graph
gr = SimpleDiGraph()
add_vertices!(gr, size(mat_arcTwoNodes, 1))
# Add edges based on the adjacency matrix
for i in 1:size(mat_arcTwoNodes, 1), j in 1:size(mat_arcTwoNodes, 2)
    if mat_arcTwoNodes[i,j] != 0
        add_edge!(gr, i, j)
    else
        nothing
    end
end
# Attach the metagraph to the original graph
mgr = MetaDiGraph(gr)
# Add the attribute of nodes
for i in 1:size(mat_arcTwoNodes,1)
    set_props!(mgr, i, Dict(
        Symbol("vec_xNode") => vec_xNode[i],
        Symbol("vec_yNode") => vec_yNode[i]
        ))
end
# Plot the graph
graphplot(gr, x=vec_xNode, y=vec_yNode)
```

The result is going to be as follow:
[image]

You may add other attributes to the plot (ask graphplot).